# how to fix error when npm install png-img or npm install hermione chai

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, npm-install, hermione

Basically I'm trying to test out Hermione (refer to tags) but ran into errors:

when I run

```
npm install hermione chai
```

I end up getting an error for installing the png-img package that ends up with something like this in the terminal:

```
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
```

I also noticed that gyp wasn't the most up to date:

```
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
```

so I naturally tried to upgrade it by:

```
npm install -g node-gyp
```

but when I retried installing hermione I still get same error, more importantly I noticed that node-gyp was still running the same older version.

After digging I also saw suggestion to install png-img by itself, ran into same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found this [link](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/wiki/Updating-npm's-bundled-node-gyp)

turns out npm has it's own internal bundle of node-gyp and you have to force upgrade it by:

```
npm explore npm -g -- npm install node-gyp@latest
```

you may need to use sudo for the above, but I believe I've also read that if you need to run sudo prior to npm commands you may have installed it wrong...